# Linux Bash - grep file with partial pathname

Tags: linux, bash

File contains fully qualified pathnames (ex `/aaa/bbb/cc`).
I need to search the file for `/bbb/cc` only.
The `/bbb/cc` is an argument to a bash script which performs the search.

My problem is the forward slashs in the argument:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print | xargs grep $1 /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but if you're looking for a regular expression to use in `grep` to match `/bbb/cc`, but not `/aaa/bbb/cc`, then you can use this:

```
$  grep '^/bbb/cc$' <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name \*.txt -exec grep `echo $1 | sed -E 's;^/[^/]+;;'` /dev/null \;
```

The sed expression will strip off the leading path component from your `$1`.  Since we're working with a pattern that has slashes in it, I've arbitrarily chosen semicolons as delimiters.  It's saying to substitute a blank (`;;`) for each line (there's just one) that begins with a slash and is followed by one or more non-slash characters.